# Counting str frequencies on Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

This is my data sample made by Pandas

`word = pd.Series[['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],['b', 'c'],['c', 'd'],['a', 'b', 'c']]`

I would like to get frequencies(1) and corpus data(2)

(1) frequencies(sorting)

```
b : 3 
c : 3
d : 2
a : 2
```

(2) corpus data(not sorting)

```
corpus = ['a b c d', 'b c', 'c d', 'a b c']
```

How can I get these? I need help

I use python for Korean NLP : This is my code

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

import itertools as it
from khaiii import KhaiiiApi # Korean NLP

df = pd.read_csv('https://drive.google.com/u/0/uc?id=1IZ1NYJmbabv6Xo7WJeqRcDFl1Z5pumni&export=download', encoding = 'utf-8')
df = pd.DataFrame(df)

api = KhaiiiApi()

def parse(sentence):
        pos = ((morph.lex, morph.tag) for word in api.analyze(sentence) for morph in word.morphs if morph.tag in ['NNG', 'VV', 'VA', 'NNP'])    # only nng, vv, va
        words = [item[0] if item[1] == 'NNG' or item[1] == 'NNP' else f'{item[0]}다' for item in pos]  # append suffix
        return words

df['내용'] = df["내용"].str.replace(",", "") 

split = df.내용.str.split(".")
split = split.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x))
split = split.stack().reset_index(level=1,drop=True).to_frame('sentences')
df = df.merge(split, left_index=True, right_index=True, how='left')
df = df.drop(['내용'], axis = 1)
df['sentences'].replace('', np.nan, inplace= True)  
df['sentences'].replace(' ', np.nan, inplace= True)
df.dropna(subset=['sentences'], inplace=True)

df['reconstruct'] = df['sentences'].apply(parse)
```

Comment: Please show your code to.

Comment: It looks like that image is just a table of numbers. It would be much easier for someone trying to answer your question if you included it as a table. There should be formatting help above the input box when you are typing your question. As @CC7052 says, showing us what you've tried will also make it easier to help you more.

Comment: Oh, I see. I fixed it

Answer (score 0):

You can get the frequencies with `value_counts` after `explode`, pandas 0.25+

```
word.explode().value_counts()
c    4
b    3
d    2
a    2
dtype: int64
```

You can get the values with

```
corpus = [' '.join(v) for k, v in word.to_dict().items()]
print(corpus)
['a b c d', 'b c', 'c d', 'a b c']
```

Comment: Thanks. you simply solved my first problem. But second problem is not solved. I want to remove [ ] ''.

Comment: Your solution seems to solve my second problem, but I don't know how to use it.

Comment: i added some variables to make it easier

Comment: Thank you very much. I wouldn't have solved it without your help!!

Comment: @DoosanPaik do you still need help here or can this question be closed